# Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [search_after] error

Tags: elasticsearch

I am making an elastic search call for a result set of 18,000 subjects. Thus I am using search_after. But I am getting following error after the very first use of this parameter.

```
Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [search_after]
```

I am using elastic search 5.1 , and the query is as follows

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "CategoryId": "1-4534"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 100,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": {"Name":"asc"} ,
  "search_after": "D106891_1"
}
```

Requirement is not to set any explicit limit on number of results that can be returned by elastic search (which defaults to 10,000) but some pagination that keeps the code free from any issue in case user data crosses a set limit in future. I am performing pagination by sending the query in a loop, getting 100 subjects in one go. This is accomplished by setting size to 100 and increment value of 
 *from*  by 100 each iteration. When I reach  *from+size = 10000* , I am adding  *search_after*  but it fails with the error mentioned above. Please let me know if I can provide with any more info. Thanks.

Comment: search_after should be an array will all the sorts key of your last results. Not a string

Comment: I made that fix and the above mentioned error went away but now I am only getting first 100 results every single iteration. I am setting _from_  to 0 as it is mentioned in [elastic search documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after)  (and -1 for once just for testing if this works) but no use.

Comment: Did you pay attention to the search after tie breaker paragraph in the documentation ? If you have too many document with the same Name it will be problematic with the search_after feature

Comment: Name is unique for all documents.

Comment: Fixed this , I had to use Name.lowercase instead of Name, as that is how I had written the index mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to use an array for search_after and Name.lowercase instead of Name, as that is how the mapping for Name attribute was written (given below )

```
           "Name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "lowercase": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                "fielddata": true
                            },
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
```